# How to compress and resize a bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

In my application I want crop image from `gallery`, after cropped convert to **base64** and send to server.
Before convert to **base64** first convert image to `bitmap`.
I want after convert to bitmap first **compress** and **resize** this `bitmap` then convert to **base64** and sent to server.
I want **10% compressed** and set **size 1000*1000** to `bitmap`.

**For crop image I use this library :** https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

**My codes:**

```
    private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) throws IOException {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (result != null) {
                Uri imageUri = Crop.getOutput(result);
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                //TODO : Here first compress and resize bitmap
                base64String = ImageConvertBase64.convert(bitmap);
   }
}
```

**before this line i should compress and resize bitmap :**

```
base64String = ImageConvertBase64.convert(bitmap);
```

How can i it? i am amateur and really need your help, please help me

Comment: `I want 10% compressed and set size 1000*1000 to bitmap.` makes no sense to me. You probably want to do the other way: **1** - Resize, **2** - compress and **3** - encode to Base64.

Comment: @KlingKlang, can you send to me code? please. i am amateur. please

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that, here. What I can do is to suggest you to follow the `divide et impera` principle. Break down your problem into smaller bits and solve these sub-problems one by one. Then put all back together and do the small cleanups and optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for the compress and resize(Set size and compression ration according to your requirement):

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);

resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,outStream);
```